# Show the $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1/k(\log k)^{1+\epsilon}<\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am working on an exercise, at the end of which I need to show

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k(\log k)^{1+\epsilon}}<\infty,\ \text{for}\ \epsilon>0\ \text{fixed}.$$

It is natural to try to get an upper bound of this series which converges, and as $k\geq 1$, we must have $$k(\log k)^{1+\epsilon}\geq (\log k)^{1+\epsilon},$$ and thus $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k(\log k)^{1+\epsilon}}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(\log k)^{1+\epsilon}},$$ but how could I show the latter series converges? does this series even make sense (since we have singularity at $k=1$)?

Thank you!

Comment: The latter series does not converge.  In fact $\sum \frac{\mathrm{d}k}{\ln^u k}$ diverges for all $u$.  For $u > 1$, by comparison with $\sum k^{-1}$.

Comment: @EricTowers oh.. okay.. then how should I show the original series converges?

Comment: The original series has the same problem with (not) being defined at $k = 1$.

Comment: @EricTowers yes I think the exercise itself has some flaw in it.... I would just argue for $k>2$.

Comment: @angryavian mostly yes. Another problem with this exercise is the $k=1$ term not defined, but perhaps it is the exercise itself's problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $L > 1$, $\frac{1}{k \ln^{1+\varepsilon}k}$ is a positive, monotonically decreasing function on $[L,\infty)$, so we may apply the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).  Using the [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) $u = \ln k$,

$$  \int_L^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}k}{k \ln^{1+\varepsilon}k} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon \ln^{\varepsilon} L}  $$

is finite, so 
$$  \sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{k \ln^{1+\varepsilon}k} $$ converges.